# Обращение к определенному в XAML словарю ресурсов из застраничного кода

Tags: c#, xaml

У меня есть словарь ресурсов,определенный в XAML-разметке,например так:

```
    <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:system="clr-namespace=System;assembly=mscorlib">
<system:String x:Key="firstField">some text</system:String>
<system:String x:Key="secondField">text</system:String></ResourceDictionary>
```

Как обратиться к такому словарю из  застраничного кода на C#(например,добавить несколько элементов)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все, уже разобрался. Необходимо создать Uri, который будет указывать на нужный словарь и присвоить его свойству Sourse нового словаря ресурсов:

```
Uri uri = new Uri(@"sample.xaml");
ResourceDictionary dict = new ResourceDictionary();
dict.Source = uri;`
```